# How to upload big data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to upload a large amount of data to mongodb.

not a file, but rather a very large amount of key value pairs.

example:

```
let payload = [];
                  
for ( let i =0 ;i<1000000;i++){
    payload.push({ 
           "first name": "juan",
           "hair color": ""+i,
           "gender" :"male"
          })
}


var body = {
    "channelId":"63dd281360e269e2a9399939",
    "recordCount":payload.length,
    "minBidUSD": 5,
    "payload": payload
}
```

the script above creates a huge payload. that payload is then put on the body of a POST request to our system.

I need to be able to store very large amounts of data in that payload.

context of functionality: I am working on a website where people can sell data leads. ex: I am looking for males in florida that are 30 years old. the possible data structure for that lead payload would be:

```
{gender:"male",state:"florida",age:30}
```

this is the question that have::

[1] is there a better way to store this data?
--note: the attributes or this payload change, so i cant create a model against it.

[2] if the best way to store this data is using gridfs-file-storage, how do I do it?

Additional notes about the question::

here is the model for the collection that holds the payload

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const channelDataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
channelId: { type: String, required: true },
payload: { type: [Object], required:true },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("ChannelData", channelDataSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gridfs is for binary data and is chunked up to avoid the 16mb MongoDB document size limitation.  I don't recommend gridfs for basic data.

For rapid data ingestion, I recommend using bulkwrite.  Here is a mongoshell example.  This example will loop creating a bunch of fake data elements made up using the `random()` function.  It is for illustration only.  If you need to insert data from a source, such as a file, or another database system you can use bulkwrite using a custom programming language, such as Node, and using the MongoDB supported database driver - which includes bulkwrite features.

**MongoShell Example:**

```
use mydatabase;


function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
    // NOT INCLUSIVE OF MAX.  IF NEED TO INCLUDE MAX, BUMP IT UP BY ONE
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
} 

function getRandomAlphaNumeric(length) {
  var result = [];
  var characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;

  for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    result.push(characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength)));
  }

  return result.join('');
}

function generateDocument() {
  return {
    stringFixedLength01: getRandomAlphaNumeric(1),
    stringFixedLength02: getRandomAlphaNumeric(2),
    stringFixedLength03: getRandomAlphaNumeric(3),
    stringFixedLength04: getRandomAlphaNumeric(4),
    stringFixedLength05: getRandomAlphaNumeric(5),
    stringVariableLength: getRandomAlphaNumeric(getRandomInteger(5, 50)),
    integer1: NumberInt(getRandomInteger(0, 2000000)),
    long1: NumberLong(getRandomInteger(0, 100000000)),
    date1: new Date(),
    guid1: new UUID()
  };
}



for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
  var batch=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    batch.push( { insertOne: { document: generateDocument() } } );
    if(i % 10000 == 0) {
        print("outerloop: " + j + ", innerloop: " + i);
    }
  }
  
  print("BulkWrite command submitted...");
  db.mycollection.bulkWrite(batch, {ordered: false});
}
```